# Missing 'which' executable on CentOS

Tags: centos, which

We booted up our CentOS (6.4 Final, kernel version 2.6.32.... i686) VM today (running on a Windows machine, yeah I know...) and for some bizarre reason the 'which' binary has gone missing. (Last week, everything was fine).

`ls -la /usr/bin` shows no `which`. Although another strange thing: there was a 'which-nodejs' symlink which pointed to a file that's missing. We since re-installed Node.js though (no 'which-nodejs' now, but it didn't help). We just noticed we're also missing the 'clear' command.

Please might anyone be able to suggest a way we could get 'which' back, without reinstalling everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with:

```
rpm -e --justdb --nodeps which
sudo yum install which
```

Still not sure what could have caused this problem though...